# How do i stop my parents from splitting

Tags: behavior

I am a teenager youngr than 16 and my dad and stepmum seem like they are going to break up.
My 3 stepbrothersdont listen to their mum and shout horrible things at her. One of them is always starting arguments with all the kids (there are 6 of us) but he has gone through alot and his mum worries about him alot and doesnt like telling him off. Basically shes soft for her kids but theyre horrible.

My dad however will always tell a kid off if they are doing something wrong but she doesnt. We are on holoday and they have spent alot of money and my dad has said that it will not work as all the kids are arguing all the time because all my stepmums kids do what they want and i react to most things but i keep out the way most the time.
By the way both parents have problems that mean they get acheing bones and hurt alot when they are stressed.

(Sorry for it being so long)

What can i do to stop this?